# How do I correctly define a function having numpy arrays as argument and return type?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

As I see it, there are two options.(Here numpy is imported as np)

**1. Using a lambda expression**

This can be used when we are dealing with a simple function. Say I want to implement the function f:(x,y) = (x^2, x+y). Then I would expect some like this to work:

`f = lambda x,y : x**2, x + y`

`f = lambda x,y : (x**2, x + y)`

when i call `print(f(np.array([[1],[3]],float)))` or `print(f(np.array([1,3],float)))`. But I cannot get any variant of these lambda expressions to work.

**2. Defining a "proper" function**

This however, does work:

```
def f(vec):
    return np.array([vec[0] ** 2, vec[0] + vec[1]])
```

But is the syntax optimal? And how would I do it if i don't want the above "proper" function to be vectorized. In total, how do i define a numpy-array valued function taking numpy-array values?

Comment: Your lambdas require 2 arguments, the def just one.  Why the difference?

Comment: Because I am not able to define a non-vectorized function f taking a 2 by 1 numpy array as argument. Logically, I understand why this is not possible, but i guess this could be fixed by calling f(fooNumpyArray[0] , fooNumpyArray[1]), right ?

Comment: In other words: I want this: f = lambda x,y : (x**2, x + y) ,                     and also be able to call it like this: f(np.array([[1],[3]])  .  What is the closest I can get to this?

Comment: There's no real difference between a `lambda` definition and a `def` one. You can use the `vec` input on either, or the `x,y`. Both can return an array or a tuple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really doesn't matter whether you use `lambda` or `def`, or do the calculation with locally defined variables.  If using functions, the number of input arguments has to match the definition.

But let's demonstrate with simple interactive examples

Define two variables:

```
In [121]: x, y = 1,3                                                                           
In [122]: x**2, x+y                                                                            
Out[122]: (1, 4)             # returns a tuple
```

Define a list:

```
In [125]: vec = [1,3]                                                                          
In [126]: vec[0]**2, vec[0]+vec[1]                                                             
Out[126]: (1, 4)             # same tuple
```

or an array:

```
In [127]: arr = np.array([1,3])
```

`[126]` would work with this too, but indexing an array is slower.

Arrays are best when we do things with the whole array, not just with elements.  For example we can square all terms of the array, or sum them.

```
In [128]: arr**2, arr.sum()                                                                    
Out[128]: (array([1, 9]), 4)
```

These calculations would work with an array of any size, not just a shape (2,).

Any of the above tuples could be converted to array:

```
In [133]: np.array([x**2, x+y])                                                                
Out[133]: array([1, 4])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the input will always be an array of length 2, you can use:

```
 f = lambda x : (x[0]**2, x[0] + x[1])
```

Then, the examples you give also work.